# Should I create separate apns certificate for notification Service Extension and notification Content Extension?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I came to know that you have to create separate app Ids and separate provisioning profile for service extensions.When I checked the created ID for notification service extension it shows that push notifications are configurable.Should I create a new apns certificate for it or can i use the base apps apns certificate?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you can't implement push notification and you can follow this tutorial https://www.appcoda.com/push-notification-ios/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After testing it out myself,it is clear that although you have to create separate appIds and provisioning profiles for extensions,you don't need to create separate apns certificate.It will work with the base apns certificate.

So the answer is ***no,it doesn't require creating separate apns certificates***.

Comment: Do need to enable Push Notifications
under the app services when create the app bundle id for extensions
?

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar I have enabled the push notifcations but haven't created separate push certificate.

Comment: okey thanks for the update even without enabling it worked for me